# Identificar caminho ou letra da unidade de DVD no autorun

Tags: vba

Estou criando uma aplicação que deve ser executada pelo DVD-R, e também é preciso executar programas de segundo plano, usando o comando `process.start("D:\Local do arquivo")`.

Mas está aí minha duvida: se o cliente tiver repartições no computador o local do disco não vai ser mais o `D:\` e sim o `F:\`.

Como eu faço para que o programa execute e outro programa de segundo plano mesmo que as unidades sejam diferentes?

Answer (score 2):

Se o aplicativo está na mesma unidade que o outro aplicativo que será disparado, você pode identificar a unidade do seu aplicativo e daí formar o caminho completo do segundo aplicativo.

Por exemplo, em vez de fixar que o outro aplicativo (no meu exemplo, *aplicativo2.exe*) está em *D:\Local do arquivo\aplicativo2.exe*, fixe apenas o seu caminho relativo à unidade raiz e crie o caminho completo a partir da unidade raiz do aplicativo que vai executá-lo:

```
    String caminhoApp = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    String unidadeApp = caminhoApp.substring(0, caminhoApp.indexOf(File.separator));

    System.out.println(unidadeApp);

    String nomeOutroApp = String.format("Local do arq%saplicativo2.exe", File.separator);
    String caminhoOutroApp = new File(unidadeApp ,nomeOutroApp).getPath();

    System.out.println(caminhoOutroApp);
```

Se você não sabe em que unidade estará o outro aplicativo, você pode fazer uma busca por unidades. Por exemplo:

```
public String localizaOutroApp(String caminhoRelativoARaiz) {
    File[] unidades = File.listRoots();
    for(int i = 0; i < unidades.length ; i++) {
        File arquivo = new File(unidades[i], caminhoRelativoARaiz);
        if (arquivo.exists()) {
            return arquivo.getPath();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Passando para a função acima o caminho do outro aplicativo relativo à raiz, ela retornará o caminho completo do outro aplicativo não importa em que unidade ele tenha sido encontrado. Exemplo:

```
// se o existe "F:\Local do arquivo\aplicativo2.exe", é este caminho que será impresso.
System.out.println(localizaOutroApp("Local do arquivo\\aplicativo2.exe"));
```

<sub>No segundo exemplo usei "\" em vez de "File.separator" para facilitar a leitura. Use sempre "File.separator" se quiser portabilidade entre sistemas operacionais.</sub>

Comment: Rodrigo, no caso eu teria que criar uma string na propriedade da minha aplicação, os codigos postado é em vb? pois estou criando uma aplicação em vb, se não for pedir muito pode da uma resumida de como fazer isso ae? pois sou novo em visual basic e estou cursando esse vai ser meu trabalho valendo nota.

Comment: @Douglas O código está em Java porque esta é a tag que você usou na sua pergunta. Cara, faz uns 15 anos que não programo em VB, não vou me aventurar por isso agora :-) Ou seria VB.Net? Ou VBA? Também não entendi "criar uma string na propriedade da minha aplicação". Corrija as tags da sua pergunta e tente colocar mais detalhes como por exemplo o que você já tentou até agora ou como está o seu código atualmente.

Comment: desculpe, me embaracei nas tags, mas valeu cara você pode não ter tirado minha duvida mas talvez tenha tirado de outro com a mesma duvida, obrigadão mesmo por ter perdido seu tempo respondendo minha duvida :D vou tentar de novo colocando tag VB.net

Comment: @Douglas Agora você colocou "VBA". É VBA ou VB.NET afinal?

Comment: VBA visual basic